# What semantic field underlies 尚?

Tags: etymology

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 799. I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A) doesn't expound what semantic notions underlie all 4 definitions, of different lexical categories, above.

> Elaboration: 甲金文從「[冂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%82)」從兩短橫(後豎起來成為「[八](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%85%AB)」)從「[口](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%A3)」，「[冂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%82)」是「[堂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A0%82)」的初文(唐蘭、陳劍)，象高出地面的堂基，「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」字是在「[冂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%82)」上部加「[八](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%85%AB)」、「[口](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%A3)」分化出來。因為「[冂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%82)」是高於地面，故「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」有高尚之義，引申為崇尚，假借為尚且。
>
> 春秋戰國文字在「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」所從的「[八](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%85%AB)」中間加一圓點為飾，圓點後來伸展為短橫或短豎。短豎和「[八](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%85%AB)」至小篆訛變為「[小](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%8F)」。
>
> 金文表示崇尚，中山王方壺：「可灋可尚」，表示可以效法，可以崇尚。又表示尚且、還(陳初生)，弔䟒父卣：「母(毋)尚為小子」，表示不要還是處於小子的階段。又通假作表示常法的「[常](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B8%B8)」，陳侯因[次月]敦：「永為典尚(常)。」《易．繫辭下》：「既有典常。」《國語．越語下》：「無忘國常」，韋昭注：「常，舊法。」又通假作表示守護的「[常](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B8%B8)」，冶仲考父壺：「子子孫孫永寶是尚(常)。」《詩．魯頌．閟宮》：「魯邦是常」，鄭玄箋：「常，守也。」又用作人名。
>
> 漢簡用作「[上](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%8A)」，表示登，《銀雀山漢簡．晏子．一三》：「景公令脩(修)茖(路)(寢)之臺，臺成，公不尚(上)焉。」表示臺建成後，景公不肯登上去。
>
> 「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」是從表示堂基的「[冂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%82)」分化出來，表示高尚的本義，引申之，登上堂基又叫「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」，這一意義的「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」傳世文獻多寫作「[上](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%8A)」，「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」、「[上](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%8A)」是音義密切相關的同源詞。中山王方壺表示上下的「[上](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%8A)」加注「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」字，成為雙聲字，「[尚](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B0%9A)」既是聲符，又是義符。

Comment: go up into a hall -> above -> respect. "still; yet" is a phonetic loan, which presumably relates to "fairly; rather"

Comment: Try this, it may help; https://baike.baidu.com/item/尚/3636?forcehttps=1%3Ffr%3Dkg_hanyu

Answer (score 1):

The basic meaning of 尚 is high(高)， so we have the word 高尚.

And you can see the glyphs of 高 and 尚 are similar, suggesting they have close origins.